# python program can't read following xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

This is the xml file :
[image]

```xml
-<Record name="AlarmRecord">

<column name="Log Serial Number">XXxxXX</column>

<column name="Object Identity">XXxxXXX</column>

</Record>
```

i get xml file like this , which i don't get it because xml column should be the column name not <column name =..."> , when i read this file with python , it doesn't recognize column names , is there a way to change this output ?
[image]

i use this functio to read the xml file and parse it

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
def parse_XML(xml_file, df_cols):     
    xtree = et.parse(xml_file)
    xroot = xtree.getroot()
    rows = []   
    for node in xroot: 
        res = []
        res.append(node.attrib.get(df_cols[0]))
        for el in df_cols[1:]: 
            if node is not None and node.find(el) is not None:
                res.append(node.find(el).text)
            else: 
                res.append(None)
        rows.append({df_cols[i]: res[i] 
                     for i, _ in enumerate(df_cols)})    
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)        
    return out_df
```

Comment: Please post an abridged version of your XML file as formatted text. And fix the indentation in your posted code.

Comment: Indentation still wrong.

Comment: Just noticed, you forgot to include `df_cols`.

Comment: i do have it in my code , but i can't post the column names for a security reason , but i have a df_cols =['column name','column2_name',...] the problem here is not in python code , but that specific xml format is unreadable

Comment: "unreadable" to you perhaps. Looks like a standard XML to me. But hey, if you say the python code is OK then why are you posting here?

Comment: as i checked , normal xml files have <'column_name'>XXXxXXX </'column_name'> but here , its <column name='zzzzzzz'>XXXxXX</column> , i tried online convertors which had the same output as this , so the solution im looking for is wether i can change the xml format , or make my python program read it that way . thank you for your time

Comment: Sorry if im being ignorant , im doing this project for a telecom company , they provide the xml files that way , its not me who codes the xml , my goal here is to analyze the data coming out of theses files , and yes i don't have any experience on xml , sorry again

Comment: Can you provide a little longer XML and not just one child node? Is `<Record>` the root node? Please provide at least root node (which may contain namespaces) and several repetition of child nodes.

Comment: @Parfait i added a corresponding picture , column names and values are hidden for a security reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building a list of dictionaries to be passed into `DataFrame` constructor with XML structure as below:

```xml
<ExportFileInfo names="AlarmRecords">
   <Record name="AlarmRecord">
      <column name="Log Serial Number">1000000</column>
      <column name="Object Identity">8888888</column>
   </Record>
   <Record name="AlarmRecord">
      <column name="Log Serial Number">2000000</column>
      <column name="Object Identity">9999999</column>
   </Record>
</ExportFileInfo>
```

**Pandas < 1.3**

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xml_file = "RecordColumnDataFrame.xml"

def parse_XML(xml_file):     
    xtree = et.parse(xml_file)
    
    data = [{column.attrib["name"]: column.text
              for column in columns.findall("column")
            } for columns in xtree.findall(".//Record")]
    
    return pd.DataFrame(data)   
    
        
df = parse_XML(xml_file)

print(df)
#   Log Serial Number Object Identity
# 0           1000000         8888888
# 1           2000000         9999999
```

**Pandas 1.3+**

And with soon to release Pandas 1.3 (~May 31, 2021), a new IO module [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#read-and-write-xml-documents) is available. However, since you have repeat child names, `column`, pass in a `names` argument and ignore the attribute, `@name`. Default parser is `lxml` but supports `etree` (what you currently use):

```py
dfcols = ["Log Serial Number", "Object Identity"]
df = pd.read_xml(xml_file, 
                 xpath = ".//Record", 
                 elems_only = True, 
                 names = dfcols, 
                 parser = "etree")

print(df)
#   Log Serial Number Object Identity 
# 0           1000000         8888888
# 1           2000000         9999999
```